# Entity framework - If nullified property, return custom string is affecting real data

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to do something like this:

```
    private string username { get; set; }
    public override string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            if( this.username == null )
            {
                return "anonymous";
            }

            return this.username;
        }
        set
        {
            this.username = value;
        }
    }
```

But when I make a change to the entity and save it, the database gets updated with `Username = "anonymous"` how can I use the getter without affecting the way the db entity stuff works?

Context:

```
ApplicationUser user = this.blah.GetUserByID(blah);// gets user from db

        user.UserDeletedAccount = true;
        user.Email = null;
        user.UserName = null;
        user.DeletedAt = now;
        user.UpdatedAt = now;
        user.PhoneNumber = null;

this.context.SaveChanges();
```

After this call, everything but the `Username` is correctly assigned to. `Username` in the database now equals `"anonymous"` which it should actually say `NULL`... I only want it so that when i'm pulling the user out into my application and try and display the username, it simply displays `"anonymous"` instead

Comment: You'll have to give some more details. What exactly are you doing?

Comment: You can't do this in entity file.. Its mapped class with database. It will automatically save populated property

Comment: I updated my OP: Do you have a recommended solution?

Comment: Your code explicitly tells EF to use "anonymous". Obviously it will do that then. Use 2 different classes: one for EF and one for presentation.

Comment: Absolutely, go with two classes like view model...

Comment: With the view model, some views I need all properties of a model... Does that mean I just have to have duplicate code everywhere for the user? Does that mean I also have to waste time remapping models to models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the reason of return anonymous is to show in a View, I think that you are mixing concepts of presentation layers with concepts of persistance layers.

If this is the case I would try another approach, like to create a ViewModel of User with this special case. Another option is to do a hack in your Model adding a property and configure it to Entity Framework to ignore.

```
public string UserNameToShow
{
    get 
    {
        if( this.username == null )
        {
            return "anonymous";
        }

        return this.username;
     }
}
```

Comment: Damn, That's a lot of code i'm going to need to change. Doh!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by seperating what you store and what you display:

```
public override string UserName { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public string UserNameDisplay
{
    get { return UserName ?? "anonymous"; }
    set { UserName = value; }
}
```